# Start() vs run() for threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm a little bit confused.

I'm trying to start a thread in a loop, i.e.:

```
while True:
  my_thread.start()
```

I'm a little confused because I've had it working with `my_thread.run()`, but when I swapped it to start() it fails to start more than one thread. Is my .run() not actually a separate thread, and if not what *should* I be doing? Lastly, can I pass variables into start()?

Comment: did you read the documentation for these methods?

Comment: Yes, but I'm struggling to find decent examples that explain the concepts.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#module-threading `start(): Start the thread’s activity. [...] run() method (is) invoked in a separate thread of control.` **VS** `run(): Method representing the thread’s activity.`

Answer (score 23):

You are correct in that `run()` does not spawn a separate thread. It runs the thread function *in the context of the current thread*.

It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve by calling `start()` in a loop.

- If you want your thread to repeatedly do something, then move the loop into the thread function.
- If you want multiple threads, then create multiple `Thread` objects (and call `start()` once on each of them).

Finally, to pass arguments to a thread, pass `args` and `kwargs` to the [`Thread` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is process live incoming video. What I want the thread to do is process the incoming frame asynchronously and then update some global vars with the results. I want it to execute a maximum of once per frame, but it's ok if it's once every few frames. The getting of frames is a continuous loop.

Answer (score 7):

## Spawn threads

You can **not** spawn *multiple* threads like this:

```
while True:
   my_thread.start()     # will start one thread, no matter how many times you call it
```

Use instead:

```
while True:
   ThreadClass( threading.Thread ).start() # will create a new thread each iteration
   threading.Thread( target=function, args=( "parameter1", "parameter2" ))

def function( string1, string2 ):
  pass # Just to illustrate the threading factory. You may pass variables here.
```

Answer (score 7):

Please read [threading code and docs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py#L854). **start()** must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the object’s **run()** method to be invoked in a separate thread of control. **run()** will be called by **start()** in the context as follow:

```
    def start(self):
        ....
        _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
        ....

    def _bootstrap(self):
        ....
        self._bootstrap_inner()
        ....

    def _bootstrap_inner(self):
        ...
        self.run()
        ...
```

Let's a demo for start() and run().

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        print("called by threading.Thread.start()")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mythread = MyThread()
    mythread.start()
    mythread.join()
```

---

```
$ python3 threading.Thread.py
called by threading.Thread.start()
```