# Difference between Process.run() and Process.start()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am struggling to understand the difference between `run()` and `start()`. According to the documentation, `run()` method invokes the callable object passed to the object's constructor, while `start()` method starts the process and can be called only once.

I tried an example below:

```
def get_process_id(process_name):
    print process_name, os.getpid()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_process_id, args=('process_1',))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_process_id, args=('process_2',))

p1.run()
p2.run()
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

The results are below:

```
process_1 35138
process_2 35138
process_1 35141
process_2 35142
```

When I use `run()`, it shows that `p1` and `p2` uses the same process. But when I use `start()`, they give the two difference ones. Is it because calling `run()` doesn't have anything to do with the process that calls it but just calling the function (which is `get_process_id` in this example)?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224784/start-vs-run-for-threads-in-python

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are not supposed to call `process.run()` explicitly. It's the method which invokes your specified `target` function unless you override it when you subclass `Process`. It normally gets called within the new child while it bootstraps. It does nothing else than calling the target function.

```
# multiprocessing.process.BaseProcess

def run(self):
    '''
    Method to be run in sub-process; can be overridden in sub-class
    '''
    if self._target:
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

When you call it in your parent process, it gets executed in your parent process like any other method.

`process.start()` is the method which you're supposed to call in your parent to create the new process in the first place.

Answer (score 11):

Invoking `start()` will create a new thread and execute `run()` in this new thread. Whereas, invoking `run()` yourself will execute it in the current thread itself. Execution of `run()` will not switch to a different thread. So it will execute its actions on the main thread itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're exactly right. As it describes in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions), `run()` is the entry point of the new thread created by `start()`.