# multiprocessing doesn't run in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to extract data from two different channels of a websocket server simultaneously. In particular, I am extracting the orderbooks of two pairs of crypto `BTC/USD` and `ZRX/USD` from the FTX Exchange. The Websocket sends an initial snapshot of the orderbooks and then it sends updates. At every message, I apply the updates.

I want to store the orderbooks in a dictionary (maybe there is a better data structure?) and I am running the two websocket connections in two different processes with `multprocessing`. I am defining two shared-in-memory dictionaries, `asks` and `bids` which will store the asks and bids side as a dictionary of a dictionary.

So for example, `asks = {'ZRX/USD':{best_askZRX: quantity_bestZRX, second_best_askZRX: quantity_second_bestZRX,..},'BTC/USD':{best_askBTC: quantity_bestBTC, second_best_askBTC: quantity_second_bestBTC,..} }` and similarly for the bids.

In the main function, I define the dictionaries and the two processes

```
manager = Manager()
asks = manager.dict()
bids = manager.dict()

asks['ZRX/USD'] = manager.dict()
bids['ZRX/USD'] = manager.dict()
asks['BTC/USD'] = manager.dict()
bids['BTC/USD'] = manager.dict()

extract_data1 = Process(target=get_orderbook, args=('ZRX/USD', asks, bids))
extract_data2 = Process(target=get_orderbook, args=('BTC/USD', asks, bids))
```

Each process calls the function `get_orderbook` defined in the code. Then I run the processes. However, the processes do not run in parallel, but `extract_data1` starts first and `extract_data2` starts only when I manually kill `extract_data1`. See the code below. What is happening here? What am I doing wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import websocket, json
import time


def on_open(ws, market):
    print('opened connection')
    subscribe_message = {'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'orderbook', 'market': market}
    print(subscribe_message)
    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_message))


def init_orderbook(ws, asks, bids, market, asks_snapshot, bids_snapshot):
    proxy_asks, proxy_bids = asks, bids
    for level in asks_snapshot:
        proxy_asks[level[0]] = level[1]
    for level in bids_snapshot:
        proxy_bids[level[0]] = level[1]
    asks, bids = proxy_asks, proxy_bids


def apply_changes(ws, asks, bids, market, asks_snapshot, bids_snapshot):
    proxy_asks, proxy_bids = asks, bids
    for level in asks_snapshot:
        if level[1] == 0:
            del proxy_asks[level[0]]
        else:
            proxy_asks[level[0]] = level[1]
    for level in bids_snapshot:
        if level[1] == 0:
            del proxy_bids[level[0]]
        else:
            proxy_bids[level[0]] = level[1]
    asks, bids = proxy_asks, proxy_bids


def on_message(ws, message, asks, bids):
    js = json.loads(message)
    if js['type'] == 'subscribed':
        print('Subscribed, ', js)
    elif js['type'] == 'update':
        market = js['market']
        update_asks = js['data']['asks']
        update_bids = js['data']['asks']
        apply_changes(ws, asks[market], bids[market], market, update_asks, update_bids)
    elif js['type'] == 'partial':
        print('Storing snapshot, ', js)
        market = js['market']
        update_asks = js['data']['asks']
        update_bids = js['data']['asks']
        init_orderbook(ws, asks[market], bids[market], market, update_asks, update_bids)

def get_orderbook(market, asks, bids):
    socket = "wss://ftx.com/ws/"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket)
    ws.on_open = lambda *x: on_open(*x, market)
    ws.on_message = lambda ws, msg: on_message(ws, msg, asks, bids)
    ws.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    asks = manager.dict()
    bids = manager.dict()

    asks['ZRX/USD'] = manager.dict()
    bids['ZRX/USD'] = manager.dict()
    asks['BTC/USD'] = manager.dict()
    bids['BTC/USD'] = manager.dict()

    extract_data1 = Process(target=get_orderbook, args=('ZRX/USD', asks, bids))
    extract_data2 = Process(target=get_orderbook, args=('BTC/USD', asks, bids))

    extract_data1.run()
    extract_data2.run()

    extract_data1.join()
    extract_data2.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing from `extract_data#.run()` to `extract_data#.start()`

[Difference between Process.run() and Process.start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084433/difference-between-process-run-and-process-start)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in the future, you should *flag the question as a duplicate* not link to another answer in an answer